# Which wood dimensions can bear X kilos at Y meters long?

Tags: design, pine

I'm making a bed frame, the edges are 2 meters long, each edge should carry 100Kg at the middle point.

Wood type is pine, how do I calculate the minimal dimensions that can bear that weight?

Is there such calculator? That would help me in other furniture projects.

Comment: Welcome to WSE!..  Try this link: http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/

Comment: So I'm trying out dimensions to achive axceptable sag. Neat, thanks !

Comment: Bear in mind the Sagulator gives average or typical figures based on published date for a given species, and in addition generally the species are native to North America (particularly true of the softwoods, including pine). So even if you live in the US you can expect that your wood may not match the given figures exactly, and if you don't live in the US your wood is guaranteed to be different. Also the grain orientation is critical to how stiff wood is in one direction or another, so in the real world a 10x10cm beam is often not equally stiff in both the x and y dimensions.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out an engineering design guide for timber construction. I believe the ones published by the American Wood Council are available for free. They also have calculators available on their website: http://awc.org/codes-standards/publications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some guidelines to consider when determining the thickness of boards to use?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/what-are-some-guidelines-to-consider-when-determining-the-thickness-of-boards-to)

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 You are right!